# Change Icon in Popup Menu Android not Work

Tags: android, popupmenu

I make a Popup Menu with Icon in item list. I want to change the icon, but it's not work. Any mistakes from my code bellow ?

```
 PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(activity, v);
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_menu_lokasi, popup.getMenu());

            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    int which= item.getItemId();

                    return true;
                }
            });

            Menu menu = popup.getMenu();

            MenuItem action_realisasi_mingguan = menu.findItem(R.id.action_realisasi_mingguan);
            action_realisasi_mingguan.setIcon(
                    new IconDrawable(getActivity(), FontAwesomeIcons.fa_arrow_right)
                            .colorRes(R.color.colorPrimary)
            );
            MenuItem action_gambar_lokasi = menu.findItem(R.id.action_gambar_lokasi);
            action_gambar_lokasi.setIcon(
                    new IconDrawable(getActivity(), FontAwesomeIcons.fa_picture_o)
                            .colorRes(R.color.colorPrimary)
            );

            // Force icons to show
            try {
                Field mFieldPopup=popup.getClass().getDeclaredField("mPopup");
                mFieldPopup.setAccessible(true);
                MenuPopupHelper mPopup = (MenuPopupHelper) mFieldPopup.get(popup);
                mPopup.setForceShowIcon(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "error forcing menu icons to show", e);
                return;
            }

            popup.show();
```

[image]

How to fix it ...? Thanks

Comment: can you post some screen shot for your activity ?

Comment: @JohnJoe cek my question again.. thanks :)